# .onkeypress not working in chrome and safari

Tags: javascript, opera

I am using the script below on my site. There is a form on the site and the idea is if user presses "enter" within that form focus should be set to another box.

The script runs perfectly in IE and FF but does not work in safari or chrome. I was originally thinking that the 2 later browsers have a different ID for the enter key however adding the "alert(evt.keyCode);"  does not produce an alert which means that it seems .onkeypress does not work in those 2 browsers. How do I fix this?

```
var WebPartElementID ="ctl00_ctl34_g_db6615a7_4c3b_4a14_9bbc_43ce9d63c24d_FormControl0";
var WebPartData = document.getElementById(WebPartElementID);    
WebPartData.onkeypress = stopRKey;    

function stopRKey(evt) {
            var evt = (evt) ? evt : ((event) ? event : null);
            var node = (evt.target) ? evt.target : ((evt.srcElement) ? evt.srcElement : null);
            alert(evt.keyCode);
            if ((evt.keyCode == 13)) { document.getElementById("ctl00_ctl34_g_db6615a7_4c3b_4a14_9bbc_43ce9d63c24d_FormControl0_V1_I1_R1_I1_T4").focus(); return false; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onkeypress

> **Notes:**
>   The keypress event should be raised when the user presses a key
>   on the keyboard. However, not all browsers fire keypress events for
>   certain keys.

Use `keyup` or `keydown` instead.

More info on differences: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/keys.html

Seems some browsers don't see the `enter` key as inserting a character.

Comment: Thanks, Keyup did not work. keydown does work. However on ff it triggers a permissions error? is there any way to catch what broswer is running and use correct function accordingly

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle or a codepen? This way I can try and look into exactly the same code you're testing with.

Comment: Thanks I figured it out. It seems keyup on firefox also triggers edit page which users don't have access to. I have added a event to stop this on master page and everything works great now.

Comment: Ah that seems to make sense, since the enter key worked with all three events in my test on chrome it had to be something else.